# Why do the officers carry bows and arrows in X-Men: Apocalypse?

Tags: plot-explanation, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-apocalypse

This scene in *X-Men: Apocalypse* contains one officer with a bow and arrow who accidentally releases it, impaling Nina and Magda.

[image: image of bow and arrow officer]

Why do the officers carry bows and arrows?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Because they know what Magneto can do. After the events of X-Men: Days of Future Past, Erik's ability to control magnetic metals are well known and he was a wanted criminal.

So after getting information about him, they avoided bringing any kind of metal at all when attempting to capture him. But going without any kind of weapon would be stupid. The bow and arrow were made of wood, giving no edge to Magneto. They also took a bat or wooden blunt object.

Comment: It's also why they kidnapped the daughter to lure him out into the woods. And if she didn't have a metal necklace they could have beaten magneto with a wooden bow and wooden bats.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, as there are other non-magnetic materials that they could use. I'm not sure about other common metals like titanium or aluminium, but at the very least, it could be made of e.g. carbon composites. Wood really wouldn't be required. In fact, I seem to recall hearing about ceramic or composite guns used for getting through metal detectors. Ruling out magnetic metals doesn't immediately mean going back to the prehistory.

Comment: @Puppy I don't think plastic guns are too easy to found but bow arrow can be easily made.  And question is "Why do the officers carry Arrows & Bows" not "Why they don't carry plastic guns", And i X-men films we never seen carbon composite weapons yet.

Comment: @AnkitSharma: Having watched the movie just a week ago, there's another detail that supports their knowledge. It is made evident that they have removed their badge before coming, further reinforcing the "getting rid of all metal pieces" instruction.